# How do I change the formatting of Xubuntu desktop icon text?

Tags: themes, fonts, xubuntu

Xubuntu 12.10, icon text is in bold. I want it regular and not bold. Where can I change this? I can't see desktop font options in any settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default theme in **Xubuntu 12.10** called **"Greybird"**...
You should try to edit the gtkrc file into the themes directory.

1. Go to the terminal and type: `sudo leafpad /usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`
2. Find the section **(style "xfdesktop-icon-view")** and **change font_name="bold"** for **font_name="regular"**

[image]

Save the file, logout and loging to see the changes..

*If you are not using the Greybird theme.. try to edit the correct file for your current theme.*

Hope will be useful!

Regards.